I don't know how to solve this error for passing an array into a class method
When I put the lakers roster into the lakers method parameters, it says:
error: unknown array size in delete
and
note: synthesized method 'Team::~Team()' first required here
Team lakers("Los Angeles Lakers", 70, 12, lakersStartRoster)//there's an arrow pointing to the last parenthesis;
The code
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    string lakersStartRoster[] = {"LeBron", "AD", "Austin", "Rui", "D'Angelo"};

    class Team {
        public:
            string name;
            int wins, losses;
            string roster[];
            Team(string x, int a, int b, string y[]){
                name = x;
                wins = a;
                losses = b;
                cout << y << endl;
            }
    };

    int main(){

        Team lakers("Los Angeles Lakers", 70, 12, lakersStartRoster);

        return 0;
    }

The Error
main.cpp:8:7: error: unknown array size in delete
        8 | class Team {
      |       ^~~~
    main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
    main.cpp:23:68: note: synthesized method 'Team::~Team()' first required here
       23 |         Team lakers("Los Angeles Lakers", 70, 12, lakersStartRoster);
          |

I got this error message on the window's powershell terminal***
I thought that I did it correctly, but I got that error message. I tried looking online for a similar problem and how to use arrays in c++, but I couldn't seem to find anything for why I'm getting this error.

That's because you have an uninitialized std::string array and when the stack tries to clean it up it throws a fit because std::string is a class with a destructor. Anyhow, you should use std::vector in this case because C arrays aren't the same as C# or Java arrays. They are static and require manual heap allocation for dynamic sizes. Just use std::vector.

Please refer to my comment for more details.
Here is the code with std::vector which is an overall better implementation for beginners.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector> // std::vector


using namespace std;

vector<string> lakersStartRoster = {"LeBron", "AD", "Austin", "Rui", "D'Angelo"};

class Team {
    public:
        string name;
        int wins, losses;
        vector<string> roster{}; // note: you never set this value in your original code
        Team(string x, int a, int b, vector<string> y){
            name = x;
            wins = a;
            losses = b;
            for(string element : y) cout << element << endl; // note: you cannot just output a vector or array itself
            roster = y; // set the value here
        }
};

int main(){

    Team lakers("Los Angeles Lakers", 70, 12, lakersStartRoster);

    return 0;
}

